# What are practical applications for markovs algorithm(string rewriting systems)

Tags: algorithms, strings, computation-models, probabilistic-algorithms, turing-completeness

:)

Currently I am browsing through the internet on the hunt for a topic for my bachelors thesis. Whilst being on Reddit I discovered an interesting repo (https://github.com/mxgmn/MarkovJunior) for a probabilistic PL that uses markovs algorithm(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_algorithm?wprov=sfti1) for some awesome labyrinths, architecture etc.

My Questions:

- Does anyone know of other practical uses for markovs algorithm?
- Does anyone know of more sources to study on the topic of markovs algorithm?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the interesting reference! Regarding the question, I used to analyse some smt string models via a tool manipulating the Markov-rules-based language Refal. Moreover, the program transformation technique named supercompilation first was developed for this language.